# How can I view downloaded .txt files as UTF-8 in Chrome on Android 13?

Tags: chrome-for-android, offline, character-encoding

We download many UTF-8 encoded .txt files.

[image: Download list]

Later in the e.g., [Northwoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northwoods_(forest)), far from the Internet, we find they are unreadable.

[image: latin1 wrong charset]

Yes, we could simply open them in a different app, but we wish to keep using Chrome. No, the files don't contain [byte order marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). Yes, there is no problem on Android 8, but things are much different on Android 13. As we observe, the `content://` URI does not pass character set information, so the browser can only assume it is [latin1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

How can I view downloaded .txt files as UTF-8 in Chrome on Android 13?

Answer (score 12):

It turns out on Android 13, in Chrome, one must manually navigate to

```
file:///sdcard/
```

and then via the directory tree to select the file.

Note, that the final "/" is important.
Without it, you will still trigger a web search (G icon) instead of being allowed to access the file system.

[image: Before slash]

[image: After slash]

Indeed, you might need to type this in letter-by-letter: `f i l e : / / / s d c a r d /` as simply pasting might not bypass the web search.

If successful, certainly do save it as a bookmark as I have.

In fact, a better way is to go into your bookmarks and pick an old unused one and then edit the contents to put the file:///sdcard/  right in there and that ought to give you a bookmark that won't get hijacked to web search. If you don't have an old unused one then make a junk one.

[image: sdcard directory]

[image: Download directory]

Voila, [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) gone!:

[image: Final cleartext]

Images taken on Samsung Galaxy, Chrome Dev 113.

Comment: Maybe it's possible to copy-paste the link, delete the last character, and type the trailing slash manually.

Comment: Or go through the internal pages, such as chrome://omnibox to disable the behavior, etc.

Comment: This works for viewing downloaded .txt files (as stated in the question), but I wanted to view other (non-downloaded) .txt files in Chrome (or Kiwi, in my case). This doesn't work for that, since other folders are not accessible now because of Scoped Storage. At the moment, I open them from MiXplorer, so they have `content://` URIs, with the wrong encoding, like in your case. I can't access those files even if I move them to the Download folder, I guess this is because [they are not in the MediaStore.Downloads table](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#media_store)